# How to resolve error running pipdeptree with Python 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pip

I'm following the instructions here for upgrading Django: [Django Upgrade Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9i1VZQg8mFg)

And I get a big error when trying to run the first command for deriving dependencies:

```
pipdeptree -f --warn silence | grep -E '^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+'
```

The following is the error stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/john.xxxx/Documents/workspace/employee-maestro/venv_3_11/bin/pipdeptree", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/Users/john.xxxx/Documents/workspace/employee-maestro/venv_3_11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipdeptree/__main__.py", line 44, in main
    render(options, tree)
  File "/Users/john.xxxx/Documents/workspace/employee-maestro/venv_3_11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipdeptree/_render/__init__.py", line 27, in render
    render_text(
  File "/Users/john.xxxx/Documents/workspace/employee-maestro/venv_3_11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipdeptree/_render/text.py", line 34, in render_text
    _render_text_with_unicode(tree, nodes, max_depth, frozen)
  File "/Users/john.xxxx/Documents/workspace/employee-maestro/venv_3_11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipdeptree/_render/text.py", line 107, in _render_text_with_unicode
    lines = chain.from_iterable([aux(p) for p in nodes])
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/john.xxxx/Documents/workspace/employee-maestro/venv_3_11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipdeptree/_render/text.py", line 107, in <listcomp>
    lines = chain.from_iterable([aux(p) for p in nodes])
                                 ^^^^^^
  File "/Users/john.xxxx/Documents/workspace/employee-maestro/venv_3_11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipdeptree/_render/text.py", line 59, in aux
    node_str = node.render(parent, frozen=frozen)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/john.xxxx/Documents/workspace/employee-maestro/venv_3_11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipdeptree/_models/package.py", line 53, in render
    return render(frozen=frozen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/john.xxxx/Documents/workspace/employee-maestro/venv_3_11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipdeptree/_models/package.py", line 114, in render_as_root
    return self.as_frozen_repr(self._obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/john.xxxx/Documents/workspace/employee-maestro/venv_3_11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipdeptree/_models/package.py", line 79, in as_frozen_repr
    fr = FrozenRequirement.from_dist(our_dist)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/john.xxxx/Documents/workspace/employee-maestro/venv_3_11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/freeze.py", line 244, in from_dist
    req, editable, comments = get_requirement_info(dist)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/john.xxxx/Documents/workspace/employee-maestro/venv_3_11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/freeze.py", line 174, in get_requirement_info
    if not dist_is_editable(dist):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/john.xxx/Documents/workspace/employee-maestro/venv_3_11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 384, in dist_is_editable
    egg_link = os.path.join(path_item, dist.project_name + ".egg-link")
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Distribution' object has no attribute 'project_name'
```

I'm new to Django and Python. I do not know how to solve this.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after staring at it for a while, I decided pip wanted something that the pipdeptree had not been tested/compiled with so I went back to an earlier version of pip and that resolved it and I got the dependency tree.

```
pip install pip==20.3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

This was the issue last year and this is the work around:

> I have figured it out. It's a pip issue. The change was made in pypa/pip#11044, between 22.1b and 22.1

> For now. If anyone wants to use pipdeptree, set _PIP_USE_IMPORTLIB_METADATA=0

Complete link to git : https://github.com/tox-dev/pipdeptree/issues/164#issuecomment-1145482711

Comment: Yes.  I saw this.  However, the advice to "set _PIP_USE_IMPORTLIB_METADATA=0" isn't very useful to someone who is unfamiliar with HOW to set that.  Could you please explain exactly what that means?  Set it where?  And how?  No offense intended, but as I am unfamiliar with the tools and language etc, I'm unable to translate that advice into actionable steps.  Thank you.